# How to create a new column where it takes value of another column when another column's condition is satisfied

Tags: r, extract, data-analysis, data-manipulation

So I have a dataset wherein I have account numbers, reporting date and Default flag.
I want to create a new column where if the default flag==1, then new column should pick that date otherwise 0.

```
Reporting date Default Flag Account Number
31-05-2006          1
30-06-2006          0
31-07-2006          0
31-08-2006          1
30-09-2006          0
31-10-2006          0
30-11-2006          1
31-12-2006          0
31-01-2007          0
```

So each account number has multiple entries, I want a new column, extracting the date whenever the Default flag hits==1.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `ifelse(df$default_flag, df$Reporting_Date, 0)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is set all values to 0 and then change the satisfied ones :

```
df[3] <- c(0,nrow(df))
D[D[,2]==1,3]=D[D[,2]==1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ifelse` here:

```
df$new_date <- ifelse(df$`Default Flag` == 1, df$`Reporting date`, 0)
```

By the way, I don't know if your column names actually haves spaces in them, but if they do, then you'll need to escape the entire name in backticks.  This can lead to ugly code, so maybe stick to single names without spaces.